# Finding all duplicates of a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby

I am looking for an efficient way to give all the duplicate values for an array.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4,7,4,4]
dups(a)

#[[2,2],[4,4,4]]
```

I've tried using brute force it by doing:

```
def dups(array)
  dups = []
  array.uniq.each do |i|
    found = array.select{|s| s.eql?(i)} 
    dups = dups.push found if found.size > 1
  end
  return dups
end
```

But it is pretty slow if you small percent of duplicate, since you are looping through the entire array.

Comment: Not exactly the desired output, but pretty efficient: `a.tally.select{|k,v| v>1 }`

Comment: @steenslag simple enough to modify though `a.tally.filter_map {|k,v| [k] * v if v > 1}`

Answer (score 3):

```
def dup_group_by(array)
  array.group_by(&:itself).filter_map { |_,v| v if v.size > 1 }
end
```

The key was group_by method which was in the Enumerable module, I was only looking in the Array class.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks! - I copy my old method and didn't clean it up; I updated it with your suggestions

Comment: Consider `array.group_by(&:itself).filter_map { |_,v| v if v.size > 1 } #=> [[2, 2], [4, 4, 4]]`. @engineersmnky, I expected that whatever you suggested in would include [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map).

Comment: @CarySwoveland agreed just wasn't trying to disagree with a viable solution from a new comer. See my comment under the original post 

Comment: @engineersmnky, that comment prompted mine.